# Python os.remove() is buffered and executed at a later point

Tags: python-3.x, io, buffering

For a test, I want to delete an SQLite database file before each run, so that the process that I am testing creates a new one each time. However, it seems that os.remove() is somehow buffered and then executes after the database has already been recreated, deleting the (already partially filled) database in the middle of my test!

Is there any method to ensure that the file has been deleted (on disk)? I do not want to disable io buffering in general, as I want to test the performance of my process in a realistic environment.

Comment: I know file writes are usually buffered, but *deleting* a file? Can you [edit] your question to show us the shortest code that replicates this problem? See also how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I will try and do that. After thinking about your comment, I may have been jumping to conclusions to fast, there is a million things that could be causing that behaviour :O I'll try and see if I can reproduce it with a minimal script.